# Why do I get this error message when I press my button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I have defined a button in my layout xml file:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/my_btn" 
   android:layout_width="30dip"
   android:layout_height="20dip" 
   android:text="@string/click_me"
   android:textSize="10dip"
/>
```

In my activity class I handle the click event with the following code:

```
 Button myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
 myBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 showToast();
            }
          });

public void showToast() {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "button clicked";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
     }
```

I run my application, when I press the button, I got the following error message from Eclipse **LogCat** console:
[image]

I do not understand what does this **error message** mean? What does it complain about? Where am I wrong?

(***Please mouse right click on the following image, and view image***)

If you got problem of viewing the above image , I write the error message here below:

```
ActivityThread | enter process activity msg=120

ActivityThread | exit process activity msg=120

WindowManager  | waitForLastKey: mFinished=true, mLastWin=null

ViewRoot enter | Dispatching touchevent to com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2fde0c80 touchevent action is 0 X=219.54167 Y=505.3675
...
...
```

P.S. I got this error after I change the button size and background drawable, sounds odd...I feel very strange too.

-----UPDATE--------

layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip">

            ...     
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/upper_text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_btn"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/upper_text1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/upper_text2"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
        android:text="@string/click_me"
                        />
...
...
```

Comment: Are you able to copy / paste the log message instead? The image is too small to read the text.

Comment: @Dan, right click -> view image. But i don't see any errors there

Comment: just right click and view it. its size is ok..

Comment: i think you are going to wrong path

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast.makeText(ClassName.this, "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

please try it

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in this line....

android:textSize="10dip"

The textSize must be specified in sp instead of dip.replace your code with->

android:textSize="10sp" and you are done!

Comment: @ Richa , where did you get the clue of 10dip is wrong? My button text size is 8dip actually...

Comment: In your Layout part you have only  mentioned. Basically we don't use dip for setting the textSize instead we use sp.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this** ::

```
 Button my_btn; 
 my_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_btn);



 my_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT). show();
}
```

Comment: @ scorpio , my toast is working previously, only after change changed my button theme, I got the error

Comment: @ scorpio , why I have to accept your answer, it does not solve my problem. You probably misunderstood my previous comment, what I meant is my toast implementation was working before, there is nothing wrong with my toast, so your answer is not the right solution to my current problem.

Comment: <Button
   android:id="@+id/my_btn" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   
   android:textSize="10dip"
/>